# Is there an XML equivalent to HTML classes?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Sorry if this is a really obvious question, but I've been trying to find something like it in a number of places, and I'm not sure if it just doesn't exist or if I'm using the wrong language to describe what I need.

If, for example, I have a number of TextViews in different parts of my activity, and I want all of them to open the same activity when clicked on, how would I do this without specifying each of their IDs individually in an if statement in the Java? In HTML I would use a class attribute to group them together, but I can't find a similar feature in XML.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I do wish people asking Android questions wouldn't use the term "XML" (or the tag "XML") as if Android-XML was the only XML vocabulary in town. This isn't a general XML question, and it shouldn't go to a general XML list.

Comment: @Michael Key, but it is a general XML question, I was just using the information for Android specifically. But in general for XML I just wanted to know if there was a class equivalent. That's about the language in general, even if I have been given Android specific solutions.

Comment: Well, XML doesn't have any notion of particular things behaving in a particular way when clicked on. Such behaviours are only defined for specific XML vocabularies.

Comment: @Michael Kay Ok fair enough. Sorry about that, the onClick was just a specific example which in hindsight was not the best. I was looking for a general answer though.

Comment: Well, the general answer is No. XML allows you to define your own vocabulary. Some XML vocabularies (e.g. DITA) have an equivalent to HTML's classes, others don't. (The concept is related, I believe, to what SGML folks call "architectural forms", though the name is horrible, but you could google it for more insight.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to prevent code repetition and tedious code repetition, then one way is to use [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). Something link below would work:

```
@OnClick({R.id.view_id1, R.id.view_id2, R.id.view_id3})
public void onClick(View view) {
   // TODO: Handle click
}
```

Or, as the other answer suggests, you can have `android:onClick` attribute on each of those views which points to same method in Java code.

Comment: Yeah that was the intention, I have just realised that I used an example in my question that very obviously had the different methods as an answer. I was looking for something that would work in lots of different cases, like if I wanted to change a bunch of text colours in different widgets all at the same time or something like that, but it seems like there really isn't a class alternative in xml. Thanks for the link though, I've never heard of that and it's very interesting so far!

Comment: There is no equivalent that I can think of but `ButterKnife` definitely helps reduce lots of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

Write your xml code of EditText as follows

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Fourth EditText"
        android:onClick="editTextClick"/>
```

And in Java file write method

```
public void editTextClick(View v) {
        // does something very interesting
        Log.d("MainActivity","EditText pressed");
    }
```

I hope this will help you,
Happy Coding

Comment: Hi! I guess using a specific function works just as well in the onClick case. I'm guessing there's no real class alternative then if, say, I wanted to set the text on a bunch of different TextViews to a certain colour all at the same time?